# MongoDB find overlapping date range on sub-documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Supposing I have this data:

```
[{
    "name": "New Training1",
    "participants": ["5d2eca379b0d361b18d2f3d0", "5d31290c21729014a0bdd0ba"],
    "schedule": [{
        "start": "2019-10-07T12:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-07T14:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "New Training2",
    "participants": ["5d2eca379b0d361b18d2f3d0"],
    "schedule": [{
        "start": "2019-10-07T14:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-07T15:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "New Training3",
    "participants": ["5d31290c21729014a0bdd0ba"],
    "schedule": [{
        "start": "2019-10-07T14:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-07T16:00:00.000Z"
    }]
}]
```

What I want to do is when I attempt to add the participant with the id of `5d2eca379b0d361b18d2f3d0` to the training `New Training3`, the app will throw an error indicating that there was a conflict on the schedule and will return the conflicting schedule. Based on the data above the system must return this training as it has a conflicting schedule:

```
{
    "name": "New Training2",
    "participants": ["5d2eca379b0d361b18d2f3d0"],
    "schedule": [{
        "start": "2019-10-07T14:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2019-10-07T15:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far.

Training model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ScheduleSchema = require('../models/schedule.model').schema;

const TrainingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Participant' }],
    schedule: [ScheduleSchema]
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Training', TrainingSchema);
```

Partcipant model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ParticipantSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
);
```

Schedule model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    start: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    },
    end: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: false
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Schedule', ScheduleSchema);
```

Function to get trainings with overlapping schedules if I add a praticpant using `participantId` to a training  with the given `trainingId`:

```
const model = require('../models/training.model');

exports.participantScheduleOverlaps = async (trainingId, participantId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    model.find(

    );
  });
};
```

I need help building a MongoDB query to find the overlapping schedule. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const util = require("util")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mongoose-doc", { useNewUrlParser: true })

const ScheduleSchema = new Schema(
    {
      start: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      end: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      }
    },
    {
      versionKey: false,
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

const TrainingSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Participant' }],
    schedule: [ScheduleSchema]
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);
const TrainingModel = mongoose.model("Training", TrainingSchema);

const ParticipantSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
);
const ParticipantModel = mongoose.model("Participant", ParticipantSchema)

async function participantScheduleOverlaps(trainingId, participantId) {

    try {
        const trainingWeFound = await TrainingModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match:{
                    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(trainingId)
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$schedule"
            }
        ]).exec()
        const otherTrainingModules = await TrainingModel.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $match:{
                        $and:[
                            {
                                _id:{
                                    $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(trainingId)
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                participants: {
                                    $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(participantId)]
                                }
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$schedule"
                }
            ]
        ).exec()
        const overlapping = otherTrainingModules.filter((otherelem) => {
            return trainingWeFound.filter(foundelem => {
                (
                    Date.parse(otherelem.start) < Date.parse(foundelem.start) 
                    &&
                    Date.parse(foundelem.start) < Date.parse(otherelem.end)
                ) || (
                    Date.parse(otherelem.start) < Date.parse(foundelem.end) 
                    &&
                    Date.parse(foundelem.end) < Date.parse(otherelem.end)
                )
            })
        })

        console.log("overlapping", overlapping)

    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
participantScheduleOverlaps("5d395604eb41824b5feb9c84", "5d31290c21729014a0bdd0ba")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for anyone who might have the same or related problem:

```
exports.participantScheduleOverlaps = async (trainingId, participantId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    model.findById(trainingId, (error, item) => {
      const result = {
        overlap: false,
        ranges: []
      };

      if (error) {
        reject(utils.buildErrObject(422, error.message));
      }

      if (item) {
        for (const schedule of item.schedule) {
          model.find(
            {
              _id: { $ne: trainingId },
              participants: { $eq: participantId },
              'schedule.end': { $gt: schedule.start },
              'schedule.start': { $lt: schedule.end }
            },
            (err, items) => {
              if (err) {
                reject(utils.buildErrObject(422, err.message));
              }

              if (items.length > 0) {
                result.overlap = true;
                result.ranges.push(
                  ...items.map(data => {
                    return data.schedule;
                  })
                );
              }

              resolve(result);
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried to implement the same with a cleaner approach. Mind trying it out? @Lemuel

Comment: @PrasantaBose I will definitely try. Thanks.